# Iron golem farm doesnt work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: My farm]

So i have this farm it worked quite well now it doesnt idk why the villagers are panicking aswell
EDIT: I raised the roof to 4 blocks instead of 3 and it worked but the golems spawn in the wall sometimes
Edit 2: Broke yet again(working and breaking)

Comment: Make sure there are no golems in the walls